# PostgreSQL select rows with specific columns identical

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get rid of rows that have the same value in only specific columns. For instance, in the extract below, I would like to select all the rows except the last one which is equal to the second-to-last row for columns CODE, START_DATE and TYPE (this means ignoring the value for END_DATE column).

```
  code         | start_date     | end_date     | type
---------------+----------------+--------------+------
C086000-T10001 | 2014-11-11     | 2014-11-12   | 01
C086000-T10001 | 2014-11-11     | 2014-11-11   | 03
C086000-T10002 | 2014-12-03     | 2014-12-10   | 03
C086000-T10002 | 2014-01-03     | 2014-01-04   | 03
C086000-T10003 | 2012-02-27     | 2014-02-28   | 03
C086000-T10003 | 2014-08-11     | 2014-11-12   | 01
C086000-T10003 | 2014-08-11     | 2014-08-20   | 01
```

How could I perform this?

**Edit:** The following query returns a *too much columns for a subquery* error message:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT code, start_date, type FROM my_table) ;
```

Many thanks for help!

Comment: No, sorry (error fixed due to copy-paste of my sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Postgres'  `distinct on` operator:

```
select distinct on (code, start_date, type) code, start_date, end_date, type
from the_table
order by code, start_date, type;
```

If you prefer to use standard SQL, this can also be done using window functions:

```
select code, start_date, end_date, type
from (
    select code, start_date, end_date, type, 
           row_number() over (partition by code, start_date, type order by end_date) as rn
    from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by code, start_date, type;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c5044/1